# How can I make these figure in a latex doc

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to add figures in my doc like these ones
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can do these graphics with TikZ, they are rather standard. Take a look at the manual, found here ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Welcome :) // What have you tried so far? Please include your codes via the Edit button. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please be more specific what you are trying to achieve, if you just want to insert those two pictures, simply use:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{YOUR PICTURE}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

If you want to draw those by yourself through the `tikz`, please show what you have done yet.